# I wish to record the output of my Tensorflow NN

Tags: tensorflow

Very new to Tensorflow, running the MNIST data set.  All runs fine, but I wish to record the output of my neural net.  I'll be darned if I can figure out how to do it.

The code I got of the web has this for the final output is:

```
output = tf.matmul(l1, output_layer['weights']) + output_layer['biases']
```

I just wish to record this output value compare it to the corresponding Label from MNIST.

I would have thought I could have used the values from the cost function (prediction and y):

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction,labels=y))
```

But I can't seem to record those values, want to write them out to a file. And I know accuracy and cost are calculated for me. Just an old geezer who likes to check work by hand.

Answer (score 1):

You can get access to any piece of your graph that you've stored in a variable. For example, from the code you've provided I see you have `cost`, `output` and `predictions` nodes.

You probably run your code via something similar to:

```
 _, c = session.run([optimizer, cost] feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

To extract values for `output` you would modify it to the following:

```
_, c, o = session.run([optimizer, cost, output] feed_dict=feed_dict)
print("Output at this step is:", o)
```

To extract values for `predictions` you would modify it to the following:

```
_, c, p = session.run([optimizer, cost, predictions] feed_dict=feed_dict)
print("Predictionsat this step is:", p)
```

Obviously you don't have to print them, you can save them to a file yourself.

**Note:** As you become more experienced with Tensorflow, you're going to want to extract more and more variables while debugging/testing. It may be in your interest to check out [Tensorboard](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/summaries_and_tensorboard). It allows you to log scalar values such as loss, histograms of all your network weights, intermediate images etc.